# Get an element's td value below an input tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following sample HTML code:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center" headers=" " class="data"><input type="checkbox" name="the-id" value="4222816"></td>
    <td headers="HDR1" class="data">RED</td>
    <td headers="HDR2" class="data">YELLOW</td>
</tr>
```

Based on the above, with jQuery, I want to be able to advance to the next td element from input inorder to obtain the value "RED"

I believe it should be something like:

```
$("input[value="4222816"]").closest('td')
```

But unsure how to get to the td value of "RED"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest` is for *ancestor* elements. You're looking for `parent().next()`: [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) to go up to the `td` containing the `input`, then [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) to go to the next element after it:

```
var text = $('input[value="4222816"]')
              .parent()
              .next()
              .text();
```

However: If you have more than one element that matches `input[value="4222816"]`, because of the set-based nature of jQuery, that will give you the text of **all** of them. ([`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text) is unusual in the jQuery world in this regard. The vast majority of jQuery's accessors would only give you the value from the first element in the set, but `text` gives you the value from *all* elements in the set.)

So if you have multiple matching elements, you'll need to narrow the selector or otherwise winnow it down to just one element.

Here's an example that uses the *first* matching element via [`.first`](http://api.jquery.com/first); but you wouldn't need that if there were only one match:

```js
$("#result").text(
  $('input[value="4222816"]')
    .first()
    .parent()
    .next()
    .text()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" headers=" " class="data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="the-id" value="4222816">
      </td>
      <td headers="HDR1" class="data">RED</td>
      <td headers="HDR2" class="data">YELLOW</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" headers=" " class="data">
        <input type="checkbox" name="the-id" value="4222816">
      </td>
      <td headers="HDR1" class="data">BLUE</td>
      <td headers="HDR2" class="data">GREEN</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>The text of the target <code>td</code> is: <span id="result"></span></p>
```

If you needed to go further that the immediately-next element, it would be `.nextAll("some-selector").first()` rather than `.next()`. (Note: Don't be fooled by the fact `next` optionally takes a selector. It doesn't find the next matching element. It either finds the next element, if it matches, or none if it doesn't.)

Comment: Appreciate the help but for some reason I am receiving more info that I am after. I expected to just get the value RED but receiving a string of info. Any ideas?

Comment: @tonyf: The above just returns `"RED"`.

Comment: Your example looks fine - just trying to work out why I am having an issue.

Comment: @tonyf: If you can add more details...?

Comment: better replicate the problem you are having in snippet so people can see what is going on :) @tonyf

Comment: Managed to track down my issue. Basically need to provide specific id at the beginning, i.e. $('#data_elem tr input[value="4222816"]').parent().next().text(); All good now.

Comment: @tonyf: Ah! Of course. I've updated the answer to clarify why and talk about addressing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
$("input[value="4222816"]").parent().next().text()
```

- [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

  > the parent() method traverses to the immediate parent of each of these elements in the DOM tree
- [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) get the next sibling

  > the .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following sibling of these elements in the DOM tree